# Read_CSV file faster

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'm having a bit of trouble reading 203 mb file quickly within the pandas dataframe. I want to know if there is a faster way I may be able to do this. Below is my function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def file(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, sep='delimiter', engine='python', skiprows=1)
    df = pd.DataFrame(df[0].str.split(',').tolist())
    df = df.drop(df.columns[range(4,70)], axis=1)
    df.columns = ['time','id1','id2','amount']
    return df
```

When i used the magic `%timeit` function it took about 6 seconds to read the file and upload it into python notebook. What can i do to speed this up?

Thanks!

Comment: `engine='python'` - from the docs: _The C engine is faster while the python engine is currently more feature-complete_ - stick with the C engine if you can.

Comment: @tdelaney, that's true, but... From docs: `Separators longer than 1 character and different from ‘s+’ will be interpreted as regular expressions, will force use of the python parsing engine and will ignore quotes in the data.`

Comment: @kma, could you post a 2-3 sample (i.e. in similar format) rows of your CSV?

Comment: @MaxU - `sep='delimiter'` means... well, I'm not quite sure. It could mean the example is not correct.

Comment: @tdelaney, it's a good point!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** looking at your logic you don't seem to need to use first  `sep='delimiter'` as you will use (split) only the first (index=0) column, so you can simply do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, usecols=[0,1,2,3],
                 names=['time','id1','id2','amount'],
                 skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1)
```

PS per default `read_csv()` will use `C` engine, which is faster, if `sep` is not longer than 1 character or if it's `\s+`

**OLD answer:**

First of all don't read columns that you don't need (or those that you are going to drop: `df.drop(df.columns[range(4,70)], axis=1)`):

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, usecols=[0], names=['txt'],
                 sep='delimiter', skiprows=1)
```

then split a single parsed columns into four:

```
df[['time','id1','id2','amount']] = df.pop('txt').str.split(',', expand=True)
```

PS i would strongly recommend to convert your data to HDF5 format (if you can) and forget about all those problems with CSV files ;)

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your help. I'm getting this error: `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 227, saw 6`

Comment: `time, id1, id2,  amount,  message,`
`2016-11-02 09:38:53, 49466, 6989, 23.74,   `
`2016-11-02 09:38:53, 52349, 8552, 37.1,  Pitcher `
`2016-11-02 09:38:53, 32639, 2562, 18.68,  ` 
`2016-11-02 09:38:53, 15381, 13167, 20.92,  For your wife.` Here is a sample of the .csv file

Comment: @kma, is it that line (227), which produces that error?

Comment: Hmm it's not showing me line (227). But the csv file is like that above. it's all in one column. When I split it it turns into 70 columns that why I drop them. But it takes so long to do all this stuff. I've never dealt with such a large file.

Comment: Essentially what i'm trying to do is connect one ID payment with another. I have two files, one and old patch of payments and a new batch of payments. Basically i'm supposed to scan through the old batch of payments and make sure it's linked to the new batch of payments by 'ID'. If there is a connection (like some un directed graph) then I return an output that says verified. If not, it's un verified.

Comment: The problem here is i have 30 million rows with I merge the payments together so to do a for loop in this case is pretty impossible.

Comment: I'm thinking about making it sparse.